# Guess the disney song from the initials number 6

Tags: music

You know what to do.
T S G W O T M T 
N A F T B S
A K O I
A I L L I T Q
T W I H L T S S I
C K I I H K I T

Comment: it's probably quite sad that I didn't even haave to look the lyrics up for this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this song

> Let it Go, a classic from Frozen?

Comment: Brilliant! How do you do these so well?

Comment: Lots and lots of Disney-movie watching, haha, @WilliamPennanti!